# Redirect to sub domain without changing URL- IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, redirect

We have a website **www.A.Com** and when I browse the URL **www.A.Com/loc**  
I need to get redirected to sub-domain **www.loc.A.Com** which is hosted by SEO provider and show the page hosted by them. 

 
The main requirement is we should not change the URL i.e. URL should remain **www.A.Com/loc**

We tried with URL Write module by defining the below Rule

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="ProxyExample" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^locations/?(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://A.Locations.com/{R:1}" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
      </serverVariables>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

One Note is Our Website is hosted on Azure App Service

Answer (score 1):

Your rule should work if you will remove `serverVariables`:

```
<rule name="ProxyExample" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^locations/?(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://A.Locations.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```